# Key function in sort method

Tags: python, sorting, methods, key

I need to sort a list of vectors, based on the last element of the vector. I thought it should be possible with the `list.sort(key=something)` method, but all I find are examples using the `sorted()` function, and I'm not clear how that key=something could point to the last element of the vector.

Here is my list of 3 vectors:

```
[ [1,2], [2,3], [3,1] ]
```

I need to reorder the 3 vectors by using the second element of each vector, and the result should produce the following

```
[ [3,1], [1,2], [2,3] ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can do that.

```
lst = [ [1,2], [2,3], [3,1] ]
def last_val_key(vec):
    return vec[-1]
lst.sort(key=last_val_key)
print lst
```

Note that the main difference between `list.sort` and `sorted` is that `list.sort` takes the list and sorts it in place whereas `sorted` creates a new (sorted) list from an arbitrary iterable that you pass in.  Both accept a `key` argument and it does the same thing in both cases.

Comment: Thank you! Your example finally made me understand how it works.